# Word 2013 won't open files downloaded (Trust Center?)

Tags: microsoft-word, windows-8.1, microsoft-word-2013

I can't open downloaded `.doc` files, unless I move it to a trusted folder. I get:

> Word experienced an error trying to open the file.

I can download and open the files on another computer with the exact same software (Windows 8.1 + Word 2013). I know I can just "trust" everything, but that defeats the purpose of the trust feature.

How do I make Word open the files without trusting the file or disabling the trust feature?

Comment: Like you said, put it in a trusted location (or add the location to the Trusted Locations list).  What's your actual question/problem? As-is it's hard to follow...

Comment: The question is: how can I open the files without trusting the files?

Comment: where are these files being saved? if they're in a browser's temp directory, you either turn off trust center OR you save them to a trusted location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *MOST LIKLEY* by design, and is for good reason. By default, Word doesn't trust files in temp directories from your browser (nor should it).

However, two ideas come to mind:

- Do a right click 'Save As' and save the file to somewhere in your local user
  directory, (Desktop / Documents / Downloads).

**OR**

- Add just your user profile to the trusted list. (not ideal, but a compromise workaround)

From Word 2010/2013: Click File > Word Options > Trust Center

[image: Trust Me!]

You could also add the root of your user directory and add subfolders if you're really having problems.

[image: This won't hurt a bit!]

**Note:** This doesn't tell word to trust *everything* but just anything in *your* local user profile directory.

Again, if these files are in a browser's temp directory, you either turn off trust center or you save them to a trusted location, it's kind of a one or the other kinda deal, as I don't think trusting your whole user director is the best solution.